# zf2 lastSequenceId() is an Invalid method?

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework2

When zf2 works, it's like magic, when it doesn't work it's maddening. I'm sure there's some little thing I'm missing or doing wrong, but what? All I want to do is get the id of the last inserted row in a postgresql table.

Here's my code:

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class LogTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'log';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Log());

        $this->initialize();
    }

    public function saveLog(Log $log)
    {
        $data = array(
            'guid'      => $log->guid,
            'user_id'   => $log->user_id,
            'client_id' => $log->client_id,
            'log_time'  => $log->log_time,
            'severity'  => $log->severity,
            'source'    => $log->source,
            'line'      => $log->line,
            'module'    => $log->module,
            'function'  => $log->function,
            'category'  => $log->category,
            'action'    => $log->action,
            'message'   => $log->message,
        );

        $id = (int)$log->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $this->insert($data);
            $id = $this->lastSequenceId('log_id_seq');
            print("id is $id");
        } else {
            if ($this->getLog($id)) {
                $this->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
            }
        }
        return $id;
    }
}
```

The inserts happen with expected regularity, but for some reason ZF2 hates the line

```
$id = $this->lastSequenceId('log_id_seq');
```

Elsewhere I've seen this:

```
$newID = $db->lastSequenceId('comments_comment_id_seq');
```

And I assumed that their $db corresponded to my $this, since they also have $db->insert and I have $this->insert.

I even tried adding this to my constructor:

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature;
...
$this->featureSet = new Feature\FeatureSet();
$this->featureSet->addFeature(new Feature\SequenceFeature('id','log_id_seq'));
```

But that just gives an error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
```

LINE 1: INSERT INTO "log" () VALUES ()

So maybe that's from another ZF2 version and doesn't work with 2.1.5.

Any idea what's going on here? Is there some way to force zf2 to give me that most recent id?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple way to do a pure equivalent to this API in PostgreSQL,  You want to drop to SQL instead and run:

```
SELECT currval('[sequence0name]');
```

So for example:

```
SELECT currval('mytable_mycol_id_seq');
```

Currval is multi-session-safe and the value is tied to the current database session.